# How can I find the file some element is loaded from?

Tags: php, drupal, ftp, google-chrome-devtools

I manage a website which is based on Drupal CMS. I have FTP access  and I want to modify the structure of the header.

I know that the header is loaded from separated php file but I don't know what is the path to the file and how to find it in FTP.

Is there any way in Chrome dev tools to find the path to the file and is there a general way to find the files from which some part is loaded?

Comment: I work with drupal and i think you need to read around it's theme layer alot more. Normally you dont edit Drupal core you would create a custom theme extending a Drupal and provide you're overrides there using .tpl.php files. After reading around the theme layer take a look at this module to help dig around theme functions/templates.. https://www.drupal.org/node/209561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under "Appearance" from admin menu what theme is used and download whole theme over FTP. Themes should be in `sites/all/themes` dir. Then search the theme files and change what you need.

I don't think that browser can be aware of theme structure since it receives the whole pages and it can not know how page html is built on server side. There is an drupal module called Theme developer which can help you with that:

https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer

Unfortunately it exists only for Drupal 6 & Drupal 7 - not sure what version of drupal uses your site.